# Why actually there is any need of WAR files in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war

Why don't one just put files in a sub directory under webapps directory?
Are there any advantages of WAR in server performance?

Comment: You mean other than being easier to deploy to different servers?  WAR and EAR are just container formats...

Comment: RAS - Reliability - Availability - Serviceability

Comment: For the same reason you download multi-file distributions as ZIP or ISO files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no performance benefit in using WAR files.  Indeed, a typical web container *unpacks* the deployed WAR file into the the webapp's directory before running the webapp ... and this takes time.

The real benefit of WAR and EAR files is in simplicity of deployment ... assuming that you are not doing something unsound like developing code on a live production server.

Answer (score 5):

WAR files are pretty much just archives, but they contain the structure of the site and package everything together in a standard format. If the files are in a WAR, they are just unpacked by the server at deploy time anyway, there isnt any performance gain except the fact that it is easier to deploy.

You could just put the items in a sub directory if you really wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The advantages of a WAR package are largely the same as for JARs. These include:

- The package can be digitally signed to ensure its authenticity.
- The package is compressed, so easier to store and deploy.
- The package can hold data about it's contents, such as vendor and version information.

Answer (score 0):

no.  its just another process to learn. the
 the tomcat server comes with detailed documentation on the deployment process including a proposed folder structure which they do not even follow in their examples. while their documentation  is comprehensive. it is not concise. a lot of it looks like filler for white-space.  in the tomcat webapps folder create a folder with the name of your project. you put your index.html, xhtml or jsp in that folder.  you need a WEB-INF under your project folder  folder which is where you put your web.xml the WEB-INF FOLDER  Also contains folders as follows:
 **classes**: this is where you drop your class files
**lib**: put your jar files here
other folders may be necessary depending on your project and its setup.  you can use a tool to deploy or do it manually.  all with the same end result.  It  would be nice to find more concise documentation on the manual processes.